# laravel passing parameter from url to route and to controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-routing

After button click from JavaScript I redirecting page with

```
 window.location.href = '//dziennik_zdarzen?id_seo=5';
```

Next i want pass it to the controller from my route this part is not working

```
Route::get('dziennik_zdarzen', ['uses'=>'Dziennik_zdarzenController@get_datatable']);
```

I attempted a lot of things like trying to get it in my controller from url but it didn't work. so im trying to pass it to Dziennik_zdarzenController@get_datatable. I changed my url to something like '//dziennik_zdarzen/5' in windows.location.href and next I tried to pass it in route. Like that:

```
Route::get('dziennik_zdarzen/{id_seo}', ['uses'=>'Dziennik_zdarzenController@get_datatable']);
```

still not working

Here is my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use App\Dziennik_zdarzen;

class Dziennik_zdarzenController extends Controller
{
  public function get_datatable($id_seo)
  {

  return $id_seo;

  }
}
?>
```

If you can guide me what im doing wrong i will be thankful

Comment: Your second route `dziennik_zdarzen/{id_seo}` looks correct, and so does your controller. What error are you getting? Might I suggest using pascalCase instead of under_scores for your parameters and action names.

Answer (score 0):

You send id_seo as query parametr. You can access it with Request object in controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
use App\Dziennik_zdarzen;

class Dziennik_zdarzenController extends Controller
{
  public function get_datatable(Request $request)
  {

      return $request->id_seo;

  }
}
?>
```

If you want send it as route parametr

```
window.location.href = '//dziennik_zdarzen/5';
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
$idSeo = request('id_seo');
```

Route:

```
Route::get('dziennik_zdarzen', 'Dziennik_zdarzenController@get_datatable');
```

No need for a use statement, dependency injection or a route parameter.